# Mapping Domain with String ID

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, mapping

I'm trying to map a domain with a table that is part of a legacy database that doesn't have an id column so I've opted for using a String id with one of the existing columns however I'm getting this error message when I try to create a new instance.

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.CannotRedirectException
Cannot redirect for object [PlanType : (unsaved)] it is not a domain or has no identifier. Use an explicit redirect instead

Here is the domain:

```
class PlanType {

static hasMany = [template:Template]

String id
String name
String description
String emailId
String initialPhase
String productType

static mapping = {

version false
table 'PLAN_TYPES'

id           generator:'assigned', name:'name', type: 'string'

name         column: 'PLAN_TYPE' 
emailId      column: 'EMAIL_ID'
initialPhase column: 'INITAL_PHASE'
productType  column: 'PRODUCT_TYPE'

}

static constraints = {
    id           (bindable:true)
    description  (maxSize:100, blank:true, nullable:true)
    emailId      (maxSize:50,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    initialPhase (maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    productType  (maxSize:20,  blank:true, nullable:true)
}       
}
```

Here is the controller

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class PlanTypeController {

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond PlanType.list(params), model:[planTypeInstanceCount: PlanType.count()]
}

def show(PlanType planTypeInstance) {
    respond planTypeInstance
}

def create() {
    respond new PlanType(params)
}

@Transactional
def save(PlanType planTypeInstance) {
    if (planTypeInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (planTypeInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond planTypeInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    planTypeInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'planTypeInstance.label', default: 'PlanType'), planTypeInstance.id])
            redirect planTypeInstance
        }
        '*' { respond planTypeInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}

def edit(PlanType planTypeInstance) {
    respond planTypeInstance
}

@Transactional
def update(PlanType planTypeInstance) {
    if (planTypeInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (planTypeInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond planTypeInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    planTypeInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'PlanType.label', default: 'PlanType'), planTypeInstance.id])
            redirect planTypeInstance
        }
        '*'{ respond planTypeInstance, [status: OK] }
    }
}

@Transactional
def delete(PlanType planTypeInstance) {

    if (planTypeInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    planTypeInstance.delete flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'PlanType.label', default: 'PlanType'), planTypeInstance.id])
            redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
    }
}

protected void notFound() {
    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args:    [message(code: 'planTypeInstance.label', default: 'PlanType'), params.id])
            redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As you decide to use `generator:'assigned'` for the id column, Hibernate lets you assign the id by yourself (see the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator)).

In the save method of your controller, i guess you do not a explicit id generation by yourself (except the case, that in params there is an key id with a valid value given, which i don't presume). Because of this, the redirect has a problem, because it does not know where to redirect to, because the id is missing.

If you really want to redirect to the new PlanType you have to be sure, that there is a proper id inplace. Alternatively you could redirect to the index method like so:

```
redirect action: 'index'
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I want to be able to create a new instance but like I said the table doesn't have an ID column so what options do I have in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a custom id, you will need to specify it to redirect method.

Here is a modified code segment from your controller:

```
        request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'planTypeInstance.label', default: 'PlanType'), planTypeInstance.name])
            redirect action: "show", id: planTypeInstance.name
        }
        '*' { respond planTypeInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace redirect planTypeInstance
with
redirect controller:"planType", id:planTypeInstance.id

in two places save closure and update closure

It definitely works

Ref:http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/CannotRedirectException-after-update-of-simple-table-td4655841.html